# how to reload the parent page from popup window without deleting control values

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-2.0

i have created two aspx pages, parent and popup page.I want to refresh parent page after some operation in popup is completed.I am using the Page.RegisterStartupscript Option for the reloading the parent page but if i call some server event from parent page that also repeat twice..i dont need that...i tried out each soln what i can do ...but nothing works so please help me out...
i am waiting for reply........
here is some code by which i am getting resend or cancel popup window from the parent page....

//In Popup.aspx.cs file

Session["txt"]=txtval.Text;
Page.RegisterStartUpScript("ReloadParent","window.opener.location.reload(false);");

//in Parent.aspx.cs file
Response.Write(Session["txt"]);

--->some event is calling after this statement in page load...

pls hel me....

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do

window.opener.__doPostBack();